# Unit test for typeorm transaction in nestjs

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to writing unit tests, I am trying to write a unit test for my nestjs project for the following code below:

```
async create(data: DeepPartial<OTPEntity>) {
  const otp = generateOTP();
  const entity = this.otpModel.create({ ...data, otp: otp.toString(), otpType: data.otpType });
  return this.dataSource.transaction(async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
    const otpData = await transactionalEntityManager.save(OTPEntity, entity);
    await this.mailService.sendOtpMail(data?.email || '', otp);
    return { id: otpData.id };
  });
}
```

I have written the test below:

```
const mockOtpData: DeepPartial<OTPEntity> = {
  id: randomUUID(),
  otp: '123456',
  validated: false,
  expiry: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 15),
  userId: randomUUID(),
  transactionUserId: randomUUID(),
  email: 'name@email.com',
  otpType: Otps.TRANSACTION_USER_PUBLIC_ACTION,
};

// Mock the dependencies
jest.mock('@bhumio/microservices-common/dist/utils/otp.util', () => {
  return {
    generateOTP: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockOtpData.otp),
  };
});

describe('OtpService', () => {
  let service: OtpService;
  let repository: Repository<OTPEntity>;
  let mailService: MailService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        OtpService,
        {
          provide: MailService,
          useValue: {
            sendOtpMail: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(OTPEntity),
          useValue: {
            create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockOtpData),
            findOne: jest.fn().mockImplementation((condition: { where: { id: string } }) => {
              return Promise.resolve(condition.where.id === mockOtpData.id ? mockOtpData : null);
            }),
            save: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockOtpData),
            update: jest.fn(),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: getDataSourceToken(),
          useValue: {
            transaction: jest
              .fn()
              .mockImplementation((transactionalFunction) => transactionalFunction({ id: mockOtpData.id })),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<OtpService>(OtpService);
    repository = module.get<Repository<OTPEntity>>(getRepositoryToken(OTPEntity));
    mailService = module.get<MailService>(MailService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('create', () => {
    it('should create an OTP and send an email', async () => {
      const inputData: DeepPartial<OTPEntity> = {
        transactionUserId: randomUUID(),
        email: 'name@email.com',
        otpType: Otps.TRANSACTION_USER_PUBLIC_ACTION,
      };
      const mockOtp = generateOTP();
      const entityData = {
        ...inputData,
        otp: mockOtp.toString(),
        otpType: inputData.otpType,
      };
      const entity = repository.create(entityData);

      await expect(service.create(inputData)).resolves.toEqual({ id: mockOtpData.id });
      expect(generateOTP).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(repository.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entityData);
      expect(repository.save).toHaveBeenCalledWith(OTPEntity, entity);
      expect(mailService.sendOtpMail).toHaveBeenCalledWith(inputData.email, mockOtp);
    });
  });
});
```

but the test is failing with the following error:

```
 ● OtpService › create › should create an OTP and send an email

    expect(received).resolves.toEqual()

    Received promise rejected instead of resolved
    Rejected to value: [TypeError: transactionalEntityManager.save is not a function]

      89 |       const entity = repository.create(entityData);
      90 |
    > 91 |       await expect(service.create(inputData)).resolves.toEqual({ id: mockOtpData.id });
         |             ^
      92 |       expect(generateOTP).toHaveBeenCalled();
      93 |       expect(repository.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entityData);
      94 |       expect(repository.save).toHaveBeenCalledWith(OTPEntity, entity);

      at expect (../node_modules/expect/build/index.js:105:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (otp/otp.service.spec.ts:91:13)
```

the function inside `dataSource.transaction` is not been executed I tried the jest callback unit test but encountered other errors.